# Openlayers 3 GeoJson save and load

Tags: openlayers, geojson, database

I am interested in openlayers 3, and I want to build a site.

Already I can load features from variable in Geojson environment and I can draw features. But I could not write a code for saving drawn features.

How can I save features - what was drawn by a user - to variable (separately coordinates from properties) in the easiest way? ( I was looking for getFeatures() function, but It did not work for me. was I right, or should I search an other option?)

If I know it I will do it with database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your code sample, there is really simple bug. I believe it's so obvious there is no need for further explanation; correct code would be:

```
function getfeatures(){
    var writer = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var geojsonStr = writer.writeFeatures(vectorSource.getFeatures());

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = geojsonStr;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. I think i do not have to mention that i am a beginner. :D :D sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for something like:

```
var writer = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var geojsonStr = writer.writeFeatures(yourVectorSource.getFeatures());
```

which converts your array of features to geoJson.

Take a look in documentation for ol.format subclasses: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.format, there are lot of supported formats, and also lot of options and methods (write single feature or array of features; write to string or object) to play around with.

After serializing features, you can save result to local variable or localstorage; or use AJAX call or WFS service (look at ol.format.WFS and writeTransaction in that case) to send result to server.

Comment: It still not works, I can get those features, what already has been stored, but I can not get the new one features(what the user draw).

Comment: Obvious explanation would be, that those new features were not stored in same source with old ones. Could you expose that part of code, where you create drawing interactions?

Comment: function addInteraction(){
        var value = typeSelect.value;
        if (value !== 'None') {
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: vectorSource,
            type: (value)       
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
            vectorSource.addFeatures(draw); /* i tried to find a solution but it is not working too.*/
            }
        else{
            map.addInteraction(select);
            map.addInteraction(modify);
            }

        }
the whole code is added as a second answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>GeoJSON</title>
    <link href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mouse_p{
              position: absolute;
              top: 10px;
              left: 10px;
              z-index: 100;
        }
        #map{
              position: relative;
              top: 30px;
              left: 30px;
              width: 800px;
              height: 300px;
        }
        #mouse_s{
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                right: 10px;
                z-index: 100;
        }
        #demo{
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                }
        #type{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" >
    <div id="mouse_p"></div>      
    <div id="mouse_s"></div></div>       
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <button onclick="getfeatures()">click me</button>
    <select id="type">
        <option value="None">Modify</option>
        <option value="Point">Point</option>
        <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
        <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      var style = {
        'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                          color: 'yellow', width: 1
                          }),
                  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)'
                          })
                  }),
            
        'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                          color: 'red', width: 1
                          }),
                  
                  }),
            };

      var styleFunction = function(feature) {
        return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
      };

      var geojsonObject = {      
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'crs': {
            'type': 'name'
            },
            'features':[]
                    };
        var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject);
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: features,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        });

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: "Vector",
            source: vectorSource,
            style: styleFunction
            
        });

        var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({layer: 'sat'})
            });
    
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [osm, vectorLayer],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({center: [2131312,6027113],zoom: 18})
                });
        var mousePosition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
            target: 'mouse_p'
                });
        
        var scaleLine = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
        target: 'mouse_s'});
        map.addControl(scaleLine);
        map.addControl(mousePosition);
        
        var draw;
        var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
        var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
        var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: select.getFeatures()
        });
        
        function addInteraction(){
            var value = typeSelect.value;
            if (value !== 'None') {
                draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: vectorSource,
                type: (value)       
                });
                map.addInteraction(draw);
                vectorSource.addFeatures(draw);
                }
            else{
                map.addInteraction(select);
                map.addInteraction(modify);
                }
            }
        
        typeSelect.onchange = function() {
            map.removeInteraction(draw);
            map.removeInteraction(select);
            map.removeInteraction(modify);
            addInteraction();
        };

        addInteraction();
        
        var writer = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var geojsonStr = writer.writeFeatures(vectorSource.getFeatures());

        function getfeatures(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = geojsonStr;
        }   
    </script>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```